# how to execute pig-0.12.1 workflow in oozie-4.0.1 using hadoop2.2

Tags: hadoop, workflow, apache-pig, scheduling, oozie

I am using hadoop-2.2,oozie-4.0.1 and pig-0.12.1. Now i moved pig library files to share/lib/pig in hdfs.
While executing pig script in oozie it goes running state and then killed. it never goes to scuccess state.

Error in logs:

```
 2014-05-27 11:37:00,404  WARN PigActionExecutor:542 - USER[labuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkflowWithPigAction] JOB[0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W] ACTION[0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W@pigAction] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2]
 2014-05-27 11:37:00,522  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[labuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkflowWithPigAction] JOB[0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W] ACTION[0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W@pigAction] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
 2014-05-27 11:37:00,565  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[labuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkflowWithPigAction] JOB[0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W] ACTION[0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W@killJobAction] Start action [0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W@killJobAction] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
 2014-05-27 11:37:00,566  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[labuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkflowWithPigAction] JOB[0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W] ACTION[0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W@killJobAction] [***0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W@killJobAction***]Action status=DONE
 2014-05-27 11:37:00,566  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[labuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkflowWithPigAction] JOB[0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W] ACTION[0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W@killJobAction] [***0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W@killJobAction***]Action updated in DB!
 2014-05-27 11:37:00,629  WARN CoordActionUpdateXCommand:542 - USER[labuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkflowWithPigAction] JOB[0000011-140527092721822-oozie-labu-W] ACTION[-] E1100: Command precondition does not hold before execution, [, coord action is null], Error Code: E1100
```

This is my workflow :

```
<workflow-app name="WorkflowWithPigAction" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
<start to="pigAction"/>
<action name="pigAction">
<pig>
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
<script>script.pig</script>
</pig>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="killJobAction"/>
</action>
<kill name="killJobAction">
<message>"Killed job due to error: ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}"</message>
</kill>
<end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

This is my job.properties :

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8032
queueName=default

oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/share/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=true

oozieProjectRoot=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/ooziepig
appPath=${oozieProjectRoot}/workflow.xml
oozie.wf.application.path=${appPath}
```

I think problem with jar files.... can any one tell me what the necessary files for pig-12.0.1 in oozie-4.0.1 uing hadoop-2.2

Help me.....

Comment: It seems you have configured something wrong. Try with new version of oozie-4.1.0. You will get success. Let me know if you have resolved the problem.